# How to write Haskell function with no parameter?

Tags: haskell

I have a function declaration called `e6`. I need to replace `undefined` by some code and make it work.

```
e6 :: Int -> Int -> Int
e6 = undefined
```

I know for example

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add a b = a + b
```

It takes parameters a and b then return a + b. But how can I write a function with no argument. I tried

```
e6 :: Int -> Int -> Int
e6 = 2 + 3
```

And it said:

> No instance for (Num (Int -> Int -> Int)) arising from a use of '+'

Comment: Do you mean you want it to *ignore* both parameters?

Comment: Well that's a constant, so `e6 = 2 + 3`, with signature `Int`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not super clear what the right fix is, because it's not super clear to me exactly what you want. Here are some possible interpretations of what you want.

- You want `e6` to be equivalent to the constant `5`, computed by evaluating `2+3`. Since this is not a function, you should not use a function type in its signature.

  ```
  e6 :: Int
  e6 = 2 + 3
  ```
- You want `e6` to be a function just like `add` is, but to always return `2+3` instead of `a+b` -- that is, to ignore its arguments, even though it still has them. Then the type signature is okay, but you need to explicitly ignore the arguments.

  ```
  e6 :: Int -> Int -> Int
  e6 _ _ = 2 + 3
  -- OR
  e6 a b = 2 + 3
  ```
- You want `e6` to be just like `add` in every way, but you don't want to explicitly name its arguments when defining `e6`. Then, if you're not giving the arguments to `e6`, you also can't give the arguments to `+`. So:

  ```
   e6 :: Int -> Int -> Int
   e6 = (+)
  ```

  `(+)` is special syntax for turning an infix operator into a prefix function; roughly, `\a b -> (+) a b` and `\a b -> a + b` behave the same way.

Comment: Sorry about my description. That helps a lot. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that Haskell is lazily evaluated, so in some sense, a variable like `e = 2 + 3` _does_ behave like a function taking zero arguments which computes `2 + 3`.

Comment: Is `(+)` really called section syntax? I thought sections are only `(+ exp)` and `(exp +)`.

Comment: @chi You might be right about that. To avoid fibbing, I've just dropped that aside for now -- what it's called isn't really important for the purposes of this answer anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Are you asking about how to write a function in [point-free style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree)?

If so, you can write the addition function as:

```
e6 = (+)
```

In this simple example, `e6` simply becomes an alias for the `+` operator. In Haskell, operators are just functions with special names, and when you want to use them as functions instead of operators, you surround them with brackets, as above. The `(+)` function (i.e. `+` operator) is already a function that takes two arguments, and returns a value.

Here's a bit of GHCi interaction with it:

```
Prelude> :t e6
e6 :: Num a => a -> a -> a
Prelude> e6 1 3
4
Prelude> e6 42 1337
1379
```

The inferred type is `Num a => a -> a -> a`, but this is also compatible with `Int -> Int -> Int`, so if you wish to constrain the type to that, you can declare the function with this more restricted type. There's no particular reason to do that, though, since the generic version works fine with `Int` as well, as the GHCi session demonstrates.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks a lot!